# counting the detected objects in an image and saving the file in directory

Tags: yolov8

I am using

> yolo task=detect mode=predict model=best.pt show=True conf=0.5 source=C:\Users\username\Desktop\images

to detect objects in images stored in a folder on desktop. the code only draws bounding boxes and detects the objects. I also want it to count the number of objects it detected in an image and save that information in the directory. can you all please help me with this. I'm running this command on cmd on windows. I am not a coding expert. I just followed a tutorial to get to the detection part. it is detecting quite well

Comment: Hi, https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2696   Does this work for you?